# As long as... which version is better?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I want to express the following:

> As long as A exists, B exists. As long as B exists, C exists.

It does not sound smooth to me. I was considering this version too:

> As long as A exists, so does B. As long as B exists, so does C.

Is it even grammatically correct? If yes, which version is better and why? Are there any alternatives?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Edit: These are the last two sentences of an essay. I would like them to carry more strength than the two versions above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are correct, but here is what you could use:

If A exists, B exists, and thus in turn, C exists.

OR

As long as A exists, B exists, and therefore, C exists.

OR

As long as A exists, B exists, and due to B's existence, C exists.